# Is it safe to shake/move macbook air while its running?

Tags: hard-drive, macbook-pro

I had this laptop and i know it's flash drive so i dont think there are moving parts, is it safe to shake it or move it without worry ? turn it upside down **while its running** ? how safe is this ?

Comment: Which Air? Can you put limits on the shaking? Is it a horrible violent off-road high speed chase or something so mild and slow that it won't even move the display hinge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things I would be worried about:

- While it's true that the MacBook Air does not have a spinning hard drive or a cd drive, it does have moving parts, namely, the fans. These should be pretty stable, but it does show that there are loose things inside the compute that could become broken due to excessive shaking.
- If the computer is running, then assumedly the display is open. In that case, I would be worried about accidentally pushing it open too far, breaking the mechanism (technically this is also a moving part). The display is also very thin, and the glass will crack if you smack it into something hard.  Personally, I would guess that the display hinge is the most likely to break if you are messing around like this.
- If something other than the magsafe is plugged into it, you're liable to break the connector.

Turning it upside down should be fine. I would avoid shaking it unless you absolutely have to. In general, if you move your computer around, there is always the risk of dropping it, or smacking or scratching some part of it on something. That risk is much higher if the display is open, because you can't hold the computer by the display, and the center of gravity is shifted away from the computer.

I'm assuming you're in a bumpy car or something. Otherwise, why are you shaking your computer?  If it's in anger, I can tell you that while it might not technically hurt, it definitely won't help.

Comment: not 'shaking' literally, just quick moves like turn it upside down, move it in all sides while its running, good answer

Answer (score 3):

It's as safe as shaking an iPad or an iPhone. Just don't drop it!